# What is the policy on "advertising" closed questions that have been revised?

Tags: discussion

I myself have a [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/245/what-is-the-biblical-stance-on-the-relation-between-women-and-god-with-regards-to) that was closed due to wording issues. I had since revised it, but no one knew about it until I told them because I hadn't edited it for hours after the close. Thus, how should people draw attention to such questions in the future?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest bringing it up in chat. I recently did this for somebody elses question to draw attention to the fact that it might be a candidate for re-opening.

If one exposure on chat fails to generate votes or useful feedback, and you felt really strongly about the question, you could create a meta post to vet out the issues. Please only do this if you have made significant changes and feel you have taken into consideration any feedback up to that point, don't do it just because you don't agree with the reasons.

If there is a problem with the reasoning, open a general meta question to discuss the general policy that lead to your question not being re-opened.

Comment: I actually DID bring it up in chat; that's the only reason for there being two re-open votes, not one. :P Also, I had considered all the feedback I got before editing the question.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman: Having reviewed your question I wouldn't have voted to re-open it because it was still going five different ways and too broad, so even if the close reason may have changed I still would leave it closed as is. See feedback there.

Comment: I'm in the process of writing a new question with your feedback in mind.